# Stencil custom page javascript not firing

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce, cornerstone

I'm trying to create a custom web page in stencil website and trying to add custom javascript module.
This is the html file named '**/templates/pages/custom/page/customz.html**'

```
    {{~inject 'template' template}}
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    <body>
    Some custom content!
    <body>
    <script>window.__webpack_public_path__ = "{{cdn 'assets/dist/'}}";</script>
    <script src="{{cdn 'assets/dist/theme-bundle.main.js'}}"></script>
    <script>window.stencilBootstrap("{{page_type}}", {{jsContext}}).load();</script>
```

This is the javascript file named '**/asset/js/theme/customz.js**'

```
import PageManager from './page-manager';

export default class Customz extends PageManager {
    onReady() {
        console.log('onReady');
    }

    constructor(context) {
        super(context);
        console.log(context);
    }
}
```

then i added this in app.js file

```
const customClasses = {
    'pages/custom/page/customz': () => import('./theme/customz')
};
```

and also added it .stencil file to test it locally
I also created the web page in bigcommerce dashboard.

The problem i have is that the HTML is loaded but the Javascript file is not injected (i cannot see the console log strings in console or other js logic i insert).

Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The place I usually start when troubleshooting a custom template is the related section on the BigCommerce Dev Center here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/storefront-customization/custom-templates#troubleshooting-template-authoring

If you've verified the version of the Stencil CLI and URL you're using, try using this same code with the base Cornerstone theme on the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

you need add link for Windows too:

Look like:

```
const customClasses = {
    'pages/custom/page/customz': () => import('./theme/customz'),
    'pages\\custom\\page\\customz': () => import('./theme/customz')
};
```

And your custom page must contains:

```
`{{~inject 'template' template}}
<script>window.__webpack_public_path__ = "{{cdn 'assets/dist/'}}";</script>
<script src="{{cdn 'assets/dist/theme-bundle.main.js'}}"></script>
<script>window.stencilBootstrap("{{page_type}}", {{jsContext}}).load();</script>`
```

If don`t connection on base file from layout.

Comment: HI, I feel your answer could be improved if you add some explanations as to why we should add those code. what does it do.

Comment: This is the standard bigcommerce documentation.